# How to backup a DB2 database OFFLINE while it is in use

Tags: db2, backup

Assume there is an application in a non-stop loop trying to read from database.
I have tried the following but it does not work:

```
db2 CONNECT TO SAMPLE
db2 QUIESCE DATABASE IMMEDIATE FORCE CONNECTIONS
db2 TERMINATE
db2 DEACTIVATE DB SAMPLE
db2 BACKUP DATABASE SAMPLE
```

It seems as if (`DEACTIVATE DB`) does not do anything since an application in a loop can still read from the database.

I keep getting the error "The database is currently in use" when trying to backup.

Answer (score 0):

You have to make sure there are not applications connected to the database (db2 list applications). Also, you have to make sure the database is not active (db2 list active databases).

Remember that a quiesce or a force applications, is a asynchronous task. It means that you execute any of them, but when the control is returned it does not mean the applications have bee disconnected.

A typical case is a rollback of a batch process, when the rollback takes several minutes.

Comment: When I do "QUIESCE DATABASE" it says "Database is already QUIESCED". I cannot stop the application whith non stop loop, so after I do "FORCE CONNECTIONS ALL" it disconnects for a seconds but then goes back to being active.

Comment: It means that the authorization ID that the application connects with has the `QUIESCE CONNECT` privilege, which allows it to connect to a quiesced database. Most commonly this happens when the application uses the instance owner ID or similar to connect, which is a bad idea in itself. There is no easy way out of this -- you'll have to block the connection at the network level, e.g. by changing the instance port (requires restart) or setting up a firewall rule to block the application IP address.

Answer (score 0):

`QUIESCE DATABASE` will not prevent new connections from coming in. I believe you have at least two choices:

1. Use `QUIESCE INSTANCE <instance> USER <username> RESTRICTED ACCESS IMMEDIATE FORCE CONNECTIONS`. This will force all existing connections and restricts access for new connections. Only the user specified in `USER` will be able to connect. Presumably, this will be your administrative account.
2. If this is a no-go, or if you are unable prevent `USER` from spawning new connections, you may want to (temporarily) `UNCATALOG DB` and/or disable the `DB2COMM` registry variable in order to prevent new connections.

HTH.

Comment: What I meant was `UNCATALOG` and then `CATALOG` using a different name - for the purpose of `BACKUP`.